# Algebraic K-theory: induced maps

Tags: abstract-algebra, k-theory, algebraic-k-theory

Let $f:A \to B$ be a homomorphism of rings. One way to define algebraic $K$ theory ($K_0$ group) is to consider the Grothendieck group of isomorphism classes of all finitely generated projective modules. Then this map $f$ induces the morphism in $K_0$ groups via the following recipe (at the level of projective modules) $P \mapsto P \otimes_{A} B$.

> I don't understand where the map $f$ is invloved, it seems that only its domain and target space matters which indicates that something is wrong.

I would also like to know how this picture corresponds to the idempotent picture. Let me quickly describe what do I mean: if $P$ is projective finitely generated $A$ module then $P$ is of the form $P=eA^n$ for some idempotent $e$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then the class of $e$ viewed as an infinite matrix (completed with zeros) with respect to the equivalence class defined by similarity via some invertible matrix defines an element of $K_0$ and there is a one-to-one correspondence between this idempotent picture and the descrpition in terms of module. However in the idempotent picture map $f$ induces the map $f_*$ where $f_*([(e_{ij})_{i,j}])=[(f(e_{ij}))_{i,j}]$.

> I would like to understand why these two aproaches are the same (at the level of induced maps).

Comment: The map $f$ is involved in making the tensor product $P\otimes_AB$. The tensor product will look different depending on $f$.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong: $P$ is an $A$-module and in order to define this tensor product we want to have a structure of $A$ module on $B$ right? So we define $a \cdot b:=f(a)b$ and then we have relations $a(x \otimes b)=ax \otimes b=x \otimes f(a)b$? EDIT: but wait, this does not make sense, we want to have a $B$ module structure on $P \otimes_{A} B$

Comment: You do have a $B$-module structure on $P\otimes_AB$ by $b(p\otimes b')=p\otimes (bb')$. The tensor product still only satisfies $(ap)\otimes b=p\otimes (f(a)b)$, for $a\in A$ though.

Comment: Ok, I understand, so only the formula $a(p \otimes b)$ does not make sense. Thank you

Comment: Well, via $f$, any $B$-module $M$ is an $A$-module by setting $a\cdot m$ to be $f(a)m$. So it does make sense. Setting $a(p\otimes b)=(ap)\otimes b$ naturally makes $P\otimes_AB$ into an $A$-module, and agrees with my previous comment defining how it would be a $B$-module.